# android Storage Access Framework write file on SD card problem

Tags: android, android-sdcard, storage-access-framework

Thank you so much for reading this question.

Currently I am about to finish my project.

However I am in a big trouble.

Although I have achieved to gain permission of writing on SD card in my app,

I cannot even google or figure out how to use this permission properly.

Does anyone know how to write file on SD card via SAF->channelSftp.get()?

Therefore, I can write on External Storage properly, but not on SD card.

Here are my code which I used to gain access to SD card.

Hope someone can help me out with a solution.

This Code is used to gain access to SD card:

```
public void takeCardUriPermission(String sdCardRootPath) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        File sdCard = new File(sdCardRootPath);
        StorageManager storageManager = (StorageManager) getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
        StorageVolume storageVolume = storageManager.getStorageVolume(sdCard);
        Intent intent = storageVolume.createAccessIntent(null);
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, 4010);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This Code is used to keep permission persistent:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 4010) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        grantUriPermission(getPackageName(), uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION |
                Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        final int takeFlags = data.getFlags() & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION |
                Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags);
    }
}
```

And This is How I implemented the permission and which keep occurs permission denied error

```
void write(String src, Uri uri){
    try {
        ParcelFileDescriptor descriptor=context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri,"w");
        if(descriptor!=null) {
            FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(descriptor.getFileDescriptor());
            channelSftp.get(src,fos);
            fos.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException | SftpException e) {
        Log.e("Error", "again "+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Again, Thank you so much for reading this and hope I get an answer someday.

Comment: There is no question. And there is nothing from Storage Access Framework.

Comment: @blackapps sorry, just edited question...I was being so hasty.

Comment: `SAF->channelSftp.get()?` ??? What do you mean with SAF? I never heard of channelSftp and you seem to use it. What is it?

Comment: `write(String src, Uri uri){` Please tell the value of `uri` and tell how you obtained that uri.

Comment: Do you want to copy a file from SFTP to SAF?

Comment: @blackapps Thank you for your attention, and first of all, ChannelSftp is an sftp fuction from java's jsch library. It is used to download file from server to client. And secondly, It would be very grateful if you show me or post a link of an example of writing file on SD card via SAF(especially with fileoutpustream). Finally, Thank you again for your attention.

Comment: Use OutputStream for the  uri. Not FileOutputStream. But then you did not tell how you obtained that uri nor did you tell its value.

Comment: @blackapps Since I had no idea of implementing SAF I just got Uri by using this code.
Uri uri  = Uri.fromFile(new File(path_of_file));

Comment: @blackapps just got the value of Uri by toString and got something like this
URI: file:///storage/E3AB-1A0D/DCIM/Camera/20200411_235128.jpg
and this isn't normal is it?

Comment: That is an invalid uri. The path will be valid but apps cannot write to that path on micro SD card as such cards are read only above Android 5. And it is no SAF uri at all.